# How to remove a kubernetes node from storageos?

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

I'm trying to remove a node from my Kubernetes cluster running at my local data center on storageos. Before doing the delete, I went ahead and checked the 'Drain' option and made sure that the node was hosting no masters or replicas. I then went ahead and did the following commands on kubernetes to remove the node:

```sh
kubectl drain <node_name> --ignore-daemonsets --delete-local-data
kubectl delete node <node_name>
ssh <node_name>
sudo kubeadm reset
```

I then went back to the storageos console to try and delete the node, but I see the following error:

"Unable to remove nodes when using internal clustering"

Anyone know what I might be doing wrong, or is this just a missing feature in storageos?

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue during evaluation of StorageOS. I installed it on Rancher with the internal etcd activated. [Here](https://docs.storageos.com/docs/operations/decommission-nodes) it says:

> This functionality is only available when StorageOS is deployed with KV_BACKEND=etcd, so the KV store is external to StorageOS. Please see the deploy etc-as-svc example for more information for more information.

This might also be your issue.